# Angular 10 value is empty in autocomplete

Tags: angular

I have the following interface that is used by my DataService :

```
export interface Shop{
  shop_name: string;
  show_owner: string;
}
```

I'm trying to use Angular Material to build [autocomplete](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples) with filter:

```
export class ShopMetaDataComponent implements OnInit {
  myControl = new FormControl();
  shops: Shop[];
  filteredShops: Observable<Shop[]>;
  selectedShop: Shop;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
  }

      ngOnInit(): void {

        // get shops metadata
        this.dataService.getShops().subscribe({
          next: data => {
            this.shops = data;
            this.initiateFilter();
          }
          ,
          error: err => console.log(err.message)
        });
      }
    
      private initiateFilter(){
        this.filteredShops= this.myControl.valueChanges
          .pipe(
            startWith(''),
            map(value => this._filter(value))
          );
      }
    
      private _filter(value: any): Shop[] {
        console.log('value : ' + value);
        const filterValue = value.shop_name.toLowerCase();
        return this.shops.filter(shop=> shop.shop_name.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
      }
```

The problem is that in the _filter method the value that is received is empty. The print that I see in the console is: `value :`
After this print I'm getting the following error in the filter method:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
```

I tried to print to the console the shops and they aren't empty.

HTML:

```
<form class="simple-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input type="text"
           placeholder="Pick one"
           aria-label="Number"
           matInput
           [formControl]="myControl"
           [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredShops| async" [value]="option">
        {{option.shop_name}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Same as in [this example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/aaaojonemken?file=src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-filter-example.ts).

What am I missing here?

### Update

Filter:

```
  private _filter(value: any): Shop[] {
    console.log('value : ' + value);
    // shop was chosen
    if (value && value.shop_name) {
      this.selectedShop= value;
    }
    // input contains text but not shop
    else if (value) {
      return this.shops.filter(option => option.shop_name.toLowerCase().includes(value));
    }
    // input doesnt contain anything
    return this.shops;
  }
```

Comment: can you share the .html file too ?

Comment: sure , in a second

Comment: Does it print an empty string when you type something ? ( the startWith method generate the first value as an empty string)

Comment: it prints an empty string and then an error raise :ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You initialize the filterValue with the shop_name but you don't check if that value is empty and if is a shop value.

You can solve this problem in two ways.

## Solution 1

check if value is an object and has one property called shop_name

```js
private _filter(value: any): Shop[] {
        if( value && value.shop_name){
            console.log('value : ' + value);
            const filterValue = value.shop_name.toLowerCase();
            return this.shops.filter(shop=> 
                shop.shop_name.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
        } else {
            return shop
        }
      }
```

### Solution 2

Change the first observable item into a shop object

```js
this.filteredShops= this.myControl.valueChanges
          .pipe(
            startWith({
                shop_name: '',
                shop_owner: ''
            }),
            map(value => this._filter(value))
          );
```

Comment: Thanks Tony ! Is there any way to determine the object that was chosen (without looping through the array and comparing shop_names - it isnt unique..). I mean, I want to hold in the frontend the object that was chosen and do with it something afterwards..

Comment: `this.myControl.value` returns the object of [value] tag, in your case the option (the shop)

Comment: Oh, you can't filter by object, because you can't type the object itself. Compare then with the name.

Comment: If I'll leave the value tag to be equal to "option" the value in my text input is changed to [object Object]. I can solve it by changing it to option.shop_name but then I wont be able to know which shop I got as my value in the filter method. (I added two lines to the orig code in the filter method)

Comment: the name isnt unique. Thats why I asked if I can both save the object that was chosen and display its name in the input.

Comment: If you leave value tag to option and leave option.show_name between {{ }} should work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219757/discussion-between-jeyj-and-tony-barletta).

Comment: When you click on one of those you set the input value to that option. You need to change the value of the input to that object and then show its value as a string (shop_name)

Comment: done that by adding the value tag to the input :            [value]="selectedShop ? selectedShop .shop_name: ''">